# Uninstalling an incompatible color theme

Tags: macos, themes

Today I did a mistake I normally never do - I blindly installed a software on my mac without knowing what I was doing.

I was looking for a dark color scheme and ran into this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XT1CqiHqUXI

Went ahead and installed the software from here http://wavespell.deviantart.com/art/Snow-Leopard-Dark-Dock-wK-155508613

Only after installing I realized that it didn't work on Lion.  Everything looks awful.  The uninstall program does not work either.  Is there a way to go back to defaults without having to reinstall the OS?  (All user accounts on this Mac are affected by this change).  Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to manually delete it. I would say that you need to open the installer again and go up to the point where it installs it, but don't install it. It should tell you where it is going to install it. From there, you can manually delete it.

Comment: Well, at the "destination select" step I am only able to select the hard disk as the install location.  I can't see a way to specify a directory or find where files are going to be copied by default...

Comment: @greppz Well, I downloaded it and didn't install it, but tried what I said. It didn't work. But, I did notice that it installs it in a .icontainer format. Figure out where those are installed and you probably can uninstall the theme.

Comment: @greppz Well, apparently, you need to use Candybar (http://www.panic.com/candybar/). Candybar is the only application that supports .icontainer files. I'll keep researching...